# Fatal error: Call to undefined method MongoCursor::toArray()

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework2, toarray, php-mongodb

I want to convert a cursor to array so i see cursor result, for this when i used toArray of mongodb then this error shown

"Fatal error: Call to undefined method MongoCursor::toArray()"

Here is my code:

```
$getting_started_collection = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Common\Collection\ResourcesGettingStarted');
$criteria = array(
    '$or' => array(
        array('affiliate_type' => 'cpl_cpm'), 
        array('affiliate_type' => 'cpl')
    )
);
$columns = array(
    '_id' => true,
    'title' => true,
    'description' => true,
    'logo' => true,
    'pdf' => true
);
$cursor = $getting_started_collection->fetchAll($criteria, $columns, true);
$data_array = $cursor->toArray();
echo("<pre>");
print_r($data_array);
die();
```

how i used https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/ ?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `MongoCursor` class does not have method called `toArray`. Here is a list of all available methods- [MongoCursor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php#mongocursor.synopsis).
You should use `iterator_to_array()` as in `Example #1` in manual:

```
<?php

$cursor = $collection->find();
var_dump(iterator_to_array($cursor));

?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php

In your example:

```
$cursor = $getting_started_collection->fetchAll($criteria, $columns, true);
$data_array = iterator_to_array($cursor);
echo("<pre>");
print_r($data_array);
die();
```

Comment: can you see this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/